# How to show scroll bar when using addOnScrollListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, scrollbar

In my app I m using addOnScrollListener. It works perfectly. But because of my list size very long i need to add scroll bar for it. I can add scrollbar with `android:scrollbars="vertical"` this code. But the scrollbar cannot be touched as you can see in the screenshot below. It can't be touched and it goes up by itself by getting smaller as you slide it down.

[image]

How can i fix that?

Comment: For that functionality you can use libraries like this

[link](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller)

Comment: Should i change addOnScrollListener? If yes what should i use instead of? Using library is my second plan. If i don't have to i don't want to use them.